# Creating variables with names of strings

Tags: java, variables

I am making an API kind of thing for school for a custom XML writer. I have:

```
public Document CreateDocument(int loops, int attr, String data[], String dataattr[][][]) {
    Document BetterDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
    Element root = BetterDoc.addElement("root");
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        Element(Object) data[i] = root.addElement(data[i])
        for (int i2 = 0; i < attr; i++) {
            .addAtribute(dataattr[i][i2][0], dataattr[i][i2][1])
        };
    }

    return BetterDoc;
}
```

The line that I want help with is:

```
Element(Object) data[i] = root.addElement(data[i])
```

I want to create an element with the same name of the data[i].

I am using the dom4j XML .jar in this, by the way.

I have heard of something called a hashmap and if this is the correct method, would someone please explain how to use it.

Comment: Please, follow Java coding conventions.
Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738010/java-print-string-c-equivalent

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153930/how-to-create-java-beans-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create dynamic variable unlike Groovy, PHP or Javascript, but you can create an array or reuse an existing variable:

With an existing variable:

```
public Document CreateDocument(int loops, int attr, String data[], String dataattr[][][]) {
    Document BetterDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
    Element root = BetterDoc.addElement("root");
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        Element _data = root.addElement(data[i]);
        for (int i2 = 0; i < attr; i++) {
            _data.addAtribute(dataattr[i][i2][0], dataattr[i][i2][1])
        };
    }    
    return BetterDoc;
}
```

With an array:

```
public Document CreateDocument(int loops, int attr, String data[], String dataattr[][][]) {
    Document BetterDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
    Element root = BetterDoc.addElement("root");
    Element[] _data = new Element[loops];
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        _data[i] = root.addElement(data[i]);
        for (int i2 = 0; i < attr; i++) {
            _data[i].addAtribute(dataattr[i][i2][0], dataattr[i][i2][1])
        };
    }    
    return BetterDoc;
}
```

You can replace array with an `ArrayList` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks alot that is what i wanted haha youre a legend xoxo

Comment: Notice that the first example was updated (compile error, data already defined) and unless you really need the `_data` array, use the first solution.

Answer (score 3):

No. Simply you can't do that. You can't create/access a variable dynamically with it's name. With Reflection you can access but you can't create.

I guess, a map can do the task here just like

```
map.put(data[i],root.addElement(data[i]);
```

Above is just an example code to throw some light.

Comment: rightyo thanks alot is there any other method you would suggest to do it?

Comment: @Piemansam5 update my post with some possible solution. Is it what you are looking for ?